# Access pod framework in main app

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a framework project which is in swift 4.(Say My ProjectName is MySDK)
I have added SDWebImage pods in it.

Now i create a framework for this project. (MYSDK.framework)

now i m including this framework in a host app. Say DemoProject
i have added the pods in Demo app as well(SDWebImage pods).

Now when i run the code(DemoProject) i get this error

ld: framework not found SDWebImage
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Your `MYSDK` is a dependent on the `SDWebImage` pod, but if you did not list it in your list of dependencies within your podfile, it will not be downloaded with your framework. Make sure your podfile adds it.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that it's not linked in the Build Phases in your project settings. Does it show up in the list under "Link Binary With Libraries"?

Comment: This should be a comment instead